# Compiler Error C2061 Error

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have the following piece of code:

```
struct TypeStruct
{
    typedef int type;
};

template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    typedef T::type type;
//          ^ this line gives compiler error
};

class Derived final :
    public Base<TypeStruct>
{

};
```

I've tried everything, searched on MSDN, without success. I really don't know what's going on. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `typedef typename T::type type;` because `type` is dependent on `T`. Read the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: @Praetorian Thank you!